# Splitting bottom window in wxpython vertically

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, splitter

I'm trying to use `wx.SplitterWindow` to split my main window into three pieces: one top window and two bottom windows (the bottom windows are left bottom and right bottom).

EDIT

Here is what I have and what I am experiencing:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import wxmplot
import wx
import os

class topPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.SetBackgroundColour("red")

class bottomLeft(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    def plotWaves(self,parent):
        self.figureWave = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figureWave.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figureWave)
        t = [ 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
        s = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.sizerWave = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizerWave.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizerWave)
        self.Fit()

########################################################################

class bottomRight(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    def plotMAW(self,parent):

        self.figureMAW = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figureMAW.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figureMAW)
        #self.axes.plot(self.waves)
        t = [ 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
        s = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.sizerMAW = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizerMAW.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizerMAW)
        self.Fit()


########################################################################

### SETUP GUI HERE
 class myGUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "myGUI", size=(850,500))

        # DEFINE A SPLIT WINDOW FOR PLOTTING
        self.splitWin = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        topP = topPanel(self)
        bottomPLeft = bottomLeft(self.splitWin)
        bottomPRight = bottomRight(self.splitWin)

        # SPLIT THE WINDOW
        self.splitWin.SplitVertically(bottomPLeft, bottomPRight)
        self.splitWin.SetMinimumPaneSize(350)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(topP, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.splitWin, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.control = p = wx.Panel(self, 1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        # SETUP CONFIG WINDOW
        self.result = wx.StaticText(p, label="")
        self.result.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self, label="Config File:")
        self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(140, -1))

        # Set sizer for the panel content
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.lblname, (1, 2))
        self.sizer.Add(self.editname, (1, 3))

        # SETUP RUN MENU
        runMenu = wx.Menu()  # create a menu for running DAQ
        runConfig = runMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "&Configure", "Load configuration file")
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(runMenu, "&Run")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onConfigure, runConfig)

        self.Show(1)
        self.aboutme = wx.MessageDialog( self, " A sample editor \n"
                            " in wxPython","About Sample Editor", wx.OK)
        self.doiexit = wx.MessageDialog( self, " Exit - R U Sure? \n",
                        "GOING away ...", wx.YES_NO)
        self.dirname = ''
    def onConfigure(self,e):
    # Load specific configuration file for system being used

        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "",
                                   "Python files (*.py)|*.py",
                                   wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        if openFileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename=openFileDialog.GetFilename()
            self.dirname=openFileDialog.GetDirectory()
            filehandle=open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename),'r')
            self.configName = self.filename[:-3]
            filehandle.close()
        lP = bottomLeft(self)
        lP.plotWaves(self)
        rP = bottomRight(self)
        rP.plotMAW(self)
        self.editname.AppendText(self.configName)
        openFileDialog.Destroy()

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = myGUI()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This is a complete example of my GUI and if you run the configure menu and load any file (it doesn't matter because that is just to run the def plotWaves and def plotMAW functions) you will see that the plots overtake the GUI. If you comment out the lines `def plotWaves(self,parent):` and `def plotMAW(self,parent):` then the plots appear in the correct place. The first image shows the result if you comment out the definition lines. The second image shows the result if you do NOT comment them out.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't defining 2 panels to make up the bottom of your display.
Is this what you are looking for:

```
import wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
class topPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        Text=wx.StaticText(self, -1, ("Top Panel"))

class bottomRight(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        Text=wx.StaticText(self, -1, ("Bottom Right"))

class bottomLeft(wx.Panel):
    # PANEL FOR PLOTTING DATA AS IT COMES IN
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        Text = wx.StaticText(self,-1,"Bottom Left")
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        t = [ 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
        s = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
        self.axes.plot(t, s)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer.Add(Text, 0,0,0,0)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

class myGUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "myGUI", size=(750,500))
        # DEFINE A SPLIT WINDOW
        self.splitWin = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        topP = topPanel(self)
        bottomPLeft = bottomLeft(self.splitWin)
        bottomPRight = bottomRight(self.splitWin)
        # SPLIT THE WINDOW
        self.splitWin.SplitVertically(bottomPLeft, bottomPRight)
        self.splitWin.SetMinimumPaneSize(350)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(topP, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.splitWin, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = myGUI()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close to what I am trying to do. The only issue is that if I make the plotting a function and then run the function somewhere else in my GUI code then the plot consumes the whole GUI and nothing else is displayed.

Comment: I suspect that that has little to do with setting up the splitter window and without code, impossible to answer

Comment: I updated my initial comment with all of my code and the results that show the issues I'm experiencing.

Comment: You are morphing your original question, into a completely different one. I suggest that you post it as a new question. Clearly the splitting the window vertically, is resolved. Remember, SO is for others with similar issues, so a question and its answer should not wander off subject.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be like this?

```
import wx


class MainGUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, size=(750,500))
        self.Centre()

        topPanel = TopPanel(self)
        hLeftPanel = LeftPanel(self)
        hRightPanel = RightPanel(self)

        hBoxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hBoxSizer.Add(hLeftPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hBoxSizer.Add(hRightPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)        

        vBoxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vBoxSizer.Add(topPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        vBoxSizer.Add(hBoxSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(vBoxSizer)


class TopPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("red")


class LeftPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("blue")


class RightPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("green")


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainGUI()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I hope I have helped!

Comment: Thank you for the help! This looks significantly better. However if I add the plot (from bottomPanel) to the LeftPanel and RightPanel classes they do not scale with the dimensions of the MainGUI class. Is this a plotting issue or a sizer issue? Thank you again!

Comment: I found a workaround for my first comment, but now I'm having issues calling functions from the LeftPanel and Right Panel classes. I tried:
   ` lP = LeftPanel(self,)
    lP().plotWaves1(self,self.configName)`
and get the error:
   ` TypeError: 'LeftPanel' object is not callable`

Comment: LeftPanel is not a method.  
  
lP = LeftPanel(self)  
lP.plotWaves1(self.configName)

Comment: I updated my first comment to show the issue I'm having completely. I used what you wrote to help split the screen but now I'm having another issue described in my edit post.